# Linux script to parse telnet message and exit

Tags: linux, bash, telnet

I am connecting to a telnet listener. Telnet server sends "1234" for every second. I want to read the message "1234" and close the telnet session. Here below is my code but it does not work.

```
#!/bin/bash
telnet 192.168.10.24 1234
read $RESPONSE
echo "Response is"$RESPONSE
echo "quit"
```

How can i automatically read the telnet message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use internal TCP mechanism:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 3<>/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/80
# echo -en "eventualy send something to the server\n" >&3
RESPONSE="`cat <&3`"
echo "Response is: $RESPONSE"
```

Or you could use nc (netcat), but please don't use telnet!

Comment: Thank you! It worked! But what is for "3<>" and "`cat <&3`". Are they for directing STDIN to RESPONSE?

Comment: You can check the REDIRECTION paragraph on the bash man page to see how /dev/tcp, exec and <> work. Substantially you are requesting bash to open for reading and writing, on the same shell, the file descriptor #3 and to attach it to a TCP stream on 127.0.0.1 port 80.

Answer (score 11):

The simplest and easiest method is given below.

```
sleep <n> | telnet <server> <port>
```

**n** - The wait time in seconds before auto exit. It could be fractional like 0.5. Note that some required output may not be returned in the specified wait time. So we may need to increase accordingly.

**server** - The target server IP or hostname.

**port** - Target service port number.

You can also redirect the output to file like this,

```
sleep 1 | telnet <server> <port> > output.log
```

**Update 1#:**
The above method may not works if the remote host doesn't accept nor drops the connection request. In those case, the following method works:

```
RESPONSE=$(timeout 5 telnet 192.168.10.24 1234)
```

Comment: pipe sleep. genius. This is the best answer.

Comment: This is what worked for me, because I was using proxychains. You taught me something new today.

Answer (score 1):

Redirect the output to a file and read from the file

```
telnet [ip-address] > /tmp/tempfile.txt
```

Comment: It is working but I am getting some unnecessary strings such as "Trying 192.168.10.24...". I think I cant use telnet for ethernet communication between devices. I think I have to implement my own socket program. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: just try to strip out the lines you dont require. like grep -v "unwanted line" <filename> will work out and socket program can be costlier than this. but again it all depends on your req.

Answer (score 1):

Already answered, but here's another point of view using curl, useful for quick checks (ie service active or not). I had to struggle a bit avoiding "script" and "expect" solutions.

Just a stub for possible POP3 check:

```
echo "quit" | curl telnet://localhost:110 > /tmp/telnet_session.txt
if grep "POP3 ready" /tmp/telnet_session.txt; then
        echo "POP3 OK"
else
        echo "POP3 KO"
fi
```